# ItextSharp C# How to add two table headers?

Tags: c#, header, itext

ItextSharp C# How to add two table headers?

I know this can add header

```
PdfPTable _pdfTable = new PdfPTable(tableRowCellCount);
_pdfTable .HeaderRows = i;
```

But i have two table

How can I add?

[image: this is my pdf]

Comment: *"But i have two table

How can I add?"* - If you have two tables, simply create two `PdfPTable` objects, each with its own header row.

Comment: thank ,I tried this as well but it didn't help